# Datepicker's present date to be highlighted in Date Picker's Dialog

Tags: android, datepicker

When I press right Arrow date in the textView is incrementing now i need that date to be set on datePicker's dialog.When i press refresh then it is setting to current date but not when i press left arrow and right arrow. What should i do to achieve that?

```
  iv_refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    count = 0;
                    getDate(count);
                    setDateTimeField();
                }
            });

            rightarrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    getDate(1);


                }
            });

            leftarraow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    getDate(-1);

                }
            });

            tv_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    icount=0;
                    DOBPickerDialog.show();

                }
            });

    public long printDifference(Date startDate, Date endDate){

            //milliseconds
            long different = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();

            System.out.println("startDate : " + startDate);
            System.out.println("endDate : "+ endDate);
            System.out.println("different : " + different);

            long secondsInMilli = 1000;
            long minutesInMilli = secondsInMilli * 60;
            long hoursInMilli = minutesInMilli * 60;
            long daysInMilli = hoursInMilli * 24;

            long elapsedDays = different / daysInMilli;
            different = different % daysInMilli;

            long elapsedHours = different / hoursInMilli;
            different = different % hoursInMilli;

            long elapsedMinutes = different / minutesInMilli;
            different = different % minutesInMilli;

            long elapsedSeconds = different / secondsInMilli;

            System.out.printf(
            "%d days, %d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds%n",
            elapsedDays,
            elapsedHours, elapsedMinutes, elapsedSeconds);

            return elapsedDays;

            }


    private void getDate(int i) {
        count = count + i;
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, count);
        currenttoday = dateFormat.format((calendar.getTime()));
    //    currenttoday = currenttoday.replace("-","/");
        tv_date.setText(currenttoday);
    //    Toast.makeText(LandingActivity.this, currenttoday, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("DateActivity");
        intent.putExtra("date", currenttoday);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

        /**
         * setDatetimefield method is used to set the selected date
         * from the datepicker to the text view
         */

        private void setDateTimeField() {

            java.util.Calendar newCalendar = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();


            DOBPickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(LandingActivity.this,R.style.pickertheme, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {


                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                    newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                    String selectDate = dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime());
                    tv_date.setText(selectDate);

                    try {
                    Date date1 = dateFormatter.parse(currenttoday);
                    String newDat = dateFormat.format(newDate.getTime());
                    Date date2 = dateFormatter.parse(newDat);
                    long diffDays = printDifference(date1, date2);
                    icount = (int) diffDays;
                    getDate(icount);

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
            }

            }

            }, newCalendar.get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(java.util.Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

> DatePickerDialog (Context context, 
>                   int themeResId, 
>                   DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener, 
>                   int year, 
>                   int monthOfYear, 
>                   int dayOfMonth)

Here, you need to pass the year, month and dayOfMonth info that you wanted to show initially in your picker.

`java.util.Calendar newCalendar = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();`

Here, you are getting a new instance of calendar, which is by default set to the current date. and by calling `newCalendar.get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(java.util.Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)`
you are telling date picker to set it to the current date. So here you need to pass the date information that is in your textview